# JSON and CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cors

I want get value from json which is there on server.

I get value by ajax.

I have message with error in console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at https:/web_page/filewith_json.php. (Reason:
>   CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

My in my file .htaccess there are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web_page.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.web_page.pl/$1 [R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Try changing '<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">' to '<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|php)$">'. Or just remove the 'FilesMatch' block completely and instead just unconditionally do 'Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"' regardless of file extension.

Comment: Your hostnames don't appear to match.

Comment: www.web_page.pl is only for example

Comment: When you replace something in your code with an example and you replace the same thing in your error message with a different example, it makes it look like a completely different problem.

Comment: yes I know, but I don't want give my page with file. That I replaced my really address.

Comment: sideshowbarker: I tried, same as ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only allow cross origin on `ttf|otf|eot|woff` files, but not on `php` files. Try replacing `FilesMatch` to this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
```

(or remove `FilesMatch` entirely)

Comment: Is the module `mod_headers.c` installed and running in apache? You can check it with `apachectl -M` in your console or in php with `<?php phpinfo();`

Comment: I used phpinfo, I don't see mod_headers.c. . I ask my admin about this module. Is it install this module I will get value from json?

Comment: Yes, this module is required to change the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` which can enable the access from another domain